# how do you send http status code 404 in static react app if page does not exist?

Tags: reactjs, http, http-status-code-404, react-router-dom

the static component Error doesnt show 404 status but 200

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Main} />
        <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
        <Route exact path='/about' component={About}/>
        <Route component={Error} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: do you mean redirect user to 404 page if a page does not exist ?

Comment: react automatically redirects to 404 page but the status is 200 there must be way to send HTTP status code